# Getting context data of one view for another view

Tags: django

I have a FormView

```
class PasswordFormView(FormView):
```

I would like to use the context_data in PasswordFormView in another form view called AuthFormView

```
class AuthFormView(FormView):

    context_data = PasswordFormView.get_context_data
```

How would I do that? Thank you

Comment: Is that edited & formatted code match with your actual code?

Comment: and what have you tried??